# iPhone screen lock notification to app

Tags: iphone

How can I be notified that the screen/phone was locked while my app is running? I want to suspend some timers related to refreshing the display in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your UIApplicationDelegate will receive the following message before the screen gets locked:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

here the link to the documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive: