# UIEvent for iPhone locking & unlocking?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am building an iPhone app in which I want to time user activity. However, I don't want to count time when the iPhone was locked (or when the user received a phone call) when calculating the times. What is the best way to do this? Is there a UIEvent which my app can receive (and act upon) when the iPhone locks or unlocks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone screen lock notification to app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651212/iphone-screen-lock-notification-to-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods `applicationWillResignActive:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Comment: I've read about this but it is for the whole application - I just want to respond to this event in a single view controller. How might i do this?